# How to set If in Assembly and then

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, cheat-engine

I'm searching for a specific value in some EAX need to change it at one specific case.

The code:

```
If EBX="000080" then

EBX = "0000200"

End If
```

But I'm running on Auto Assemble. So far
if need to change the value

```
mov ebx,0000200

else

mov [esi+48],ebx
```

How If then can be implemented on Assembly?

```
mov ebx,200

else

mov [esi+48],ebx
```

Comment: Putting numbers inside quotes will make a string / character constant, won't it?  Like a 4-byte integer made of the ASCII codes for `0` and `2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    cmp ebx, 80
    jne 1f
    mov ebx, 200
    jmp 2f
1:  mov [esi+48], ebx
2:
```